# Minecraft client randomly crashes playing on a Spigot or Vanilla server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have created 1.15.1 spigot server and managed to get some of my friends on the server. They have told me that there minecraft keeps crashing on my minecraft server with the error `exeception_access_violotion`. If they go and play on another server they don't get this issue at all.This doesn't happen when they join but they might just be breaking a block or fighting a mob and then the game would freeze then their game would crash I first thought this might of been a memory issue for the client so I changed the allocation of memory to 512MB on the client. I still got the same error so I don't think it is a memory issue. I don't think it is the server running out of memory either as the server only uses about half of what I've allocated it at any given time.

The server runs some datapacks with the overworld. I have removed all datapacks this didn't resolve the issue. I have also updated the graphic drivers as well it still occurred in fact I believe it made the crashes more frequent.

I have considered changing the server from spigot to a plain vanilla server from the official minecraft site since im not using any plugins and wont require them if i have datapacks. So the question is if I change the server to vanilla would this resolve the random crashes and if so why doesn't it happen with spigot and there are no server crashes or logs about this. I think the problem could also be a general connection issue to the server but this wouldn't explain why the client crashes if it is a connection issue

Update: I have changed the server to vanilla and still get the crash. However it seems to be less frequent. Here is the crash report: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7tbji2ac5r3kht/hs_err_pid21640.log?dl=0

Comment: A full crash log would be helpful. And yes, you should try a Vanilla server and at least see whether the problem is the same there or not.

Comment: I have changed the server to vanilla and still get the crash. However it seems to be less frequent. As for the crash report: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7tbji2ac5r3kht/hs_err_pid21640.log?dl=0

Comment: I have just been playing a bit more and tried taking a screenshot and this failed by what looks to be the game not having permission to create or remove files. And in the crash report something similar seems to occur could it be that the client doesnt have access to modify files.

Comment: Flagging as off-topic because, per the creator's April 30 answer, "I realized that I was using a cracked version of the game. I fixed this by paying for the proper game", meaning this question is about illegal software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about pirated games are off topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about [support for pirated (cracked) games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are off topic on Arqade.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for one of the method names on the bug tracker and found this: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-145102

It seems like this issue is related to timing. No workaround is known, but trying to (re)connect multiple times should usually work at some point.

The best you can do to get this bug fixed is voting for it on the bugtracker (and telling others who are affected by it) and commenting whenever you can confirm it in a new version.

Answer (score 0):

After some time and noticing some other issues that were occuring in the game I realized that I was using a cracked version of the game. I fixed this by paying for the proper game and using the correct launcher. I guess this only happened in the newer versions as the cracked launcher was no longer being maintained.

Comment: After further research this war partially caused by using the 32-bit version of java. This only meant that java could only run minecraft with one gigabit of allocated memory. I changed the java to 64-bit and changed the launcher to run the game with at least 2GB or RAM